# Make 2 applications behave like 1

Tags: php, reactjs, wordpress, jwt

i've a Wordpress Project. I authenticate users over the WP API via JWT in my custom react.js frontend. At the `/shop` slug, i have a WooCommerce Shop running (which is also the one where i auth my users via jwt) where you have to signin seperatly. Now the Shop and Custom Frontend should behave like one without 2 sign in's. Is there any possibility to do this?

Comment: Yes it is possible (as an example look at something like google which even logs you in on multiple subdomains). You need to figure how the shop does the login and how it verifies that the user is still logged in. You have to copy the code/idea/logic to your custom frontend. How do you do that? By looking at the code. If you have any **specific** questions then update your question.